Divider to take up whole width JetpackCompose
I am very new to Jetpack Compose / Kotlin so please don't judge but I am at wits ends here. I have a LazyVerticalGrid and then below it a LazyColumn. To separate the two I added a HorizontalDivider. My problem is I can't figure out how to get the HorizontalDivider to take up the view of the whole screen. I've tried adjusting the paddings, increasing the width, playing around with the modifier and now luck. Here is the list portion:
@Composable
fun ItemList(
    itemList: List<String>, // Pass the list of items
    listState: LazyListState // Pass the LazyListState
) {
    if (itemList.isNotEmpty()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            HorizontalDivider(
                thickness = 2.dp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
            )

            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(400.dp),
                state = listState // Use the LazyListState
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(itemList) { index, item ->
                    // Row for the list item
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                            .background(
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                                RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                            )
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(12.dp),
                            text = item,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
                        )
                    }

                    // Separator (Divider) after each item except the last one
                    if (index < itemList.size - 1) {
                        HorizontalDivider(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
                            thickness = 1.dp,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Your padding is being added at a layer above the code you've provided. Please include the code all the way up to your root layout.
